# Get a smooth CSS steps animation-ending

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm using CSS animations to animate sprites from many keyframes that are inline in a PNG file.

```
@keyframes rotate {
  from {background-position: 0 0;}
  to {background-position: -2560px 0;}
}
.rotate{
      animation: rotate 0.75s steps(20) infinite;
}
```

I use JS to add or remove .rotate on user interaction.
The animations work well, but when removing .rotate, the sprite go back immediately to it's initial state.
When I remove .rotate, I want the sprite to be animated until it comes to its initial state. Only at this moment the animation stops.

I read about steps(number [, start | end]), but I don't know if it can help me.

Comment: What is the interaction?

Comment: Try toggling `animation-direction` between `forwards` and `backwards` as well when you toggle the animation

Comment: When user clicks on an element, it toggles .rotate on this element

Comment: I got all the sprites to have a complete animation without using animation-direction. I thought about delay on animation-ending, but does that exist ?

Comment: If the rotate class is added on click, when is it removed? On click again?

Comment: Yes, one click to add, one click to remove.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Animation Play State](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp) property? Then you could just start it out as paused and on click toggle between running and paused.

Comment: I didn't know this property existed. It could be quite what I want (sprites would pause on another frame than the first, but why not ...).
About performance, I've got 64 of them running one at a time. Does pausing affects performance instead of setting/removing the animation ?

Comment: I found that animation events exists in JS. I could listen to the end of animation, and only at this time remove .rotate.